# redistribute data in Gaussian distribution with pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, normal-distribution

I have a pandas DataFrame which contain probabilities of each sample belonging to each class (columns). It such happened that almost 99 % of classes have `< 0.01` probability and very few have `> 0.5` probabilities. For some reason, I want the probabilities to be distributed in Gaussian distribution between `0` and `1`. I guess the mean should be `0.5` in such case, but I would also like to be able to modify the mean of such distribution if that is possible.
I want this operation for each row separately, how can I do it using pandas dataframe?

Comment: Do you want to modify such probabilities in each row, in order to reproduce a more gaussian-like distribution?

Comment: @GianfrancescoAngelini Yes, I want to modify each row in such distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reproduce a more Gaussian-like distribution you're talking about weigthing of single points (class score in a row).
So I would suggest to use Guassian distributed weights to amplify the score.

Here an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#Preparation of the data
nclasses = 10
nsamples = 5
df_c = []
for nc in range( nsamples ):
    a = np.random.rand(nclasses)
    a = [n/np.sum(a) for n in a]
    df_c.append( a )

df = pd.DataFrame(df_c)

# Now let's weight

for nr in range( df[0].count() ): #iterate over rows
    a = df.iloc[nr] #capture the nth row
    #generate Gaussian weights
    gw = np.random.normal( np.mean(a), np.std(a), len(a) )
    #sort gw and a in order to assign one to the other
    gw = np.sort(gw)
    b_ind = np.argsort(a) #indexes to sort a
    b = a[b_ind]          #sorted version of a
    # now weight the row
    aw_r = a*b # you can reduce the entity adding anotherfactor, like 0.8 for instance
    # back from sort
    aw = [ aw_r[n] for n in b_ind ]
    #update the dataframe
    df.iloc[nr] = aw

# there you go!
```

Hope it will be helpful

**Update**__
If you want to adjust the mean of every row to a same value, for instance 0.5, you just have to subtract the difference between the row mean and the target mean (0.5 in this case).

```
a=np.array([1,2,3,47,2,6])
print( a.mean() ) # 10.1666
target_mean = 0.5

a_adj = a-(np.mean(a) - target_mean)
print( np.mean( a_adj ) ) # 0.5
```

It means that in the main example above, before substituting aw in df.iloc[nr] you should do

```
aw = aw-(np.mean(aw) - 0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! BTW how can I adjust the mean of the distribution in this code?

Comment: Do you want to adjust the single row mean, leaving each row different from the others, or do you want to obtain a unique mean along all the rows?

Comment: I need a single unique mean for all the rows. Thanks.